# Removing JSON element of array in Python with same file descriptor

Tags: python, json, serialization

I have a JSON file that has an array of objects like this:

```
{
  "array": [
    {
      "foo1": "bar",
      "spam1": "eggs"
    },
    {
      "foo2": "bar",
      "spam2": "eggs"
    },
    {
      "foo3": "bar",
      "spam3": "eggs"
    }
  ]
}
```

And what I'm trying to do in Python is to read a JSON file, then remove an element of an array and then write the contents back to the file. I expect the file to be exactly the same, just without that element, but the problem is that when I write the contents back, they are corrupted in a weird way.

When I run this code:

```
import json

CONTENTS = {
  "array": [
    {
      "foo1": "bar",
      "spam1": "eggs"
    },
    {
      "foo2": "bar",
      "spam2": "eggs"
    },
    {
      "foo3": "bar",
      "spam3": "eggs"
    }
  ]
}

# Write that object to file
with open("file.json", "w") as file:
    json.dump(CONTENTS, file, indent=2)

# You can check here to see the file
input()

# Modify the file
with open("file.json", "r+") as file:
    contents = json.load(file)

    file.seek(0)

    print(contents)
    del contents["array"][-1]  # Delete the last object of the array
    print(contents)

    json.dump(contents, file, indent=2)
```

The file after the second `open` is exactly like this:

```
{
  "solves": [
    {
      "foo1": "bar",
      "spam1": "eggs"
    },
    {
      "foo2": "bar",
      "spam2": "eggs"
    }
  ]
}{
      "foo3": "bar",
      "spam3": "eggs"
    }
  ]
}
```

As I said, I was expecting the file to be the same, just without the last object of the array, but instead it is... wrong.

Am I actually doing something wrong? I had no problem **changing** an object's field or **appending** an object to that same array in the same `with` block or with the same file descriptor.

My questions are: What am I doing wrong? Is the problem the fact that I read AND write to the file? How can I fix it, besides doing this:

```
with open("file.json", "r+") as file:
    contents = json.load(file)

del contents["array"][-1]  # Delete the last object of the array

with open("file.json", "w") as file:
    json.dump(contents, file, indent=2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you overwrite the file you need to truncate it to remove the excess JSON at the end.

```
with open("file.json", "r+") as file:
    contents = json.load(file)

    file.seek(0)

    print(contents)
    del contents["array"][-1]  # Delete the last object of the array
    print(contents)

    json.dump(contents, file, indent=2)
    file.truncate()
```

Comment: Is it necessary to seek the file twice? I don't think so. I already did that in my question above.

Comment: I didn't see that. Then the important part is truncate.